# Читалка книг: книги в виде отдельных приложений

Tags: android

Добрый день!

Передо мной встала задача: разработать читалку под Android для своего формата книг. Сам по себе этот формат - просто набор html, css, js. Но сами книги не просто текст и картинки, в них есть интерактивные упражнения вроде тестирования, перетаскиваний, рисования и т.д. То есть использовать существующие форматы я не могу. Решили распространять книги в виде отдельных Android приложений, так как видели такое же решение у другого издательства (то есть у нас есть главное приложение читалки и много отдельных приложений с книгами, которые сами по себе не являются программами с Activity, а просто добавляют в список книг новую книгу).

Собственно вопрос:
1. Как создать такое приложение-книгу (без значка запуска в списке приложений, и чтобы оно устанавливало книгу, при удалении, соотв., удаляло)?
2. Как читалка может получить доступ к таким книгам?

Надеюсь на вашу помощь!